# Как сделать переопределение атрибута класса обязательным

Tags: python, ооп, классы, атрибуты

У меня есть класс `BaseWeapon` как сделать так, чтобы после наследования его другим классом обязательно нужно было переопределять атрибут `self.stats`?
Предполагаю, что нужно использовать модуль abc из стандартной библиотеки.
Класс BaseWeapon:

```
class BaseWeapon:
CLASS = 'weapon'

class Stats:
    def __init__(self, power):
        self.power = power

def __init__(self, owner, name):
    self._owner = owner
    self._name = name
    self._stats = None

@property
def stats(self):
    return self._stats

@stats.setter
def stats(self, another_stats):
    if isinstance(another_stats, self.Stats):
        self._stats = another_stats
    else:
        raise TypeError(f'Value must be Stats class, not {type(another_stats).__name__}')
```

Примеры ожидаемых подклассов:

```
class NoWeapon(BaseWeapon):
def __init__(self, owner):
    super().__init__(owner, 'Empty')
    self.stats = self.Stats(power=1)

class Claws(BaseWeapon):
def __init__(self, owner):
    super().__init__(owner, 'Claws')
    self.stats = self.Stats(power=10)
```

Comment: Как вариант решения вашей задачи - не определять атрибут в родительском классе вовсе. В таком случае при любом обращении к методам будет вызываться `AttributeError`, т.к. атрибута нет, а обращение к нему в методе есть

Comment: @Евгений Какой именно параметр? _stats или может property stats?

Comment: не объявлять `_stats` внутри родительского `__init__`. Ведь его вам нужно обязать переопределять?

Comment: чёт фигня-все мечи 10 повара будут ? пусть лучше клас принимает этотот стат при создании

Comment: @Евгений именно так, обязательно. Спасибо, это действительно решает проблему

Comment: @Интик все Claws на 10, остальные классы переопределят статы под свои нужды

Comment: @Евгений а как возможно указать пользователю, что self.stats должен быть переопределен?

Comment: @Code Is my life  а зачем они с одинаковым поваром ? можнож градацию по цветам сделать, по уровням. артефактные или читорские.

Comment: @CodeIsmylife документация/описание класса

Comment: @Интик прочитай про полиморфизм, поймешь почему "повар" не будет одинаковый

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете вовсе не объявлять `_stats` в родительском классе, но всё также обращаться к нему в методах этого класса.
Результатом такого решения будет то, что при попытке вызвать любой метод класса будет вызван `AttributeError`, если `_stats` не был определён в классе-наследнике.
Фактически это указывает на то, что `_stats` нужен, но его ещё нет, потому его нужно определить.

Не забывайте указывать это в документации либо описании класса.

```py
class BaseWeapon:
  """
  Дочерний класс обязан определить атрибут _stats
  """
  CLASS = 'weapon'

  class Stats:
      def __init__(self, power):
          self.power = power

  def __init__(self, owner, name):
      self._owner = owner
      self._name = name
      # self._stats = None - убрать

  @property
  def stats(self):
      return self._stats

  @stats.setter
  def stats(self, another_stats):
      if isinstance(another_stats, self.Stats):
          self._stats = another_stats
      else:
          raise TypeError(f'Value must be Stats class, not 
 {type(another_stats).__name__}')
```